# MassTransit is not able to produce messages to a Kafka topic in Confluent Cloud due to message size that is too large

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, masstransit

Before I continue with my question, let me summarize which technologies I'm using first.

**Current situation**

*Using:*

- MassTransit (InMemory)
- Confluent Cloud (Apache Kafka Cluster is running here)
- Visual Studio 2022 (IDE)
- ASP.NET Core Web API (backend)
- C# (backend)
- JavaScript (frontend)

**My question/problem I'm facing:**

At the moment I try to send an image file to a Apache Kafka topic within Confluent Cloud, but I get an error that is saying that the message size is too big. I've checked the MassTransit configuration as well as the configuration of the Kafka topic in Confluent Cloud. Message sizes of at least 2.5 MB are allowed (based on my given input) to be able to go through the Kafka topic. I also did this in the MassTransit configuration. However, I'm not able to send images bigger than 1 MB to an Apache Kafka topic.

**Configuration**

*MassTransit - Producer*

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.UsingInMemory((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
    
    x.AddRider(rider =>
    {
        rider.AddProducer<[...Event...]>(topicName: "<TOPIC NAME...>");
        
        rider.UsingKafka((riderContext, kafkaFactory) => 
        {
            kafkaFactory.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslSsl;
            kafkaFactory.MessageMaxBytes = 2500000; //DOES NOT WORK...
            kafkaFactory.Host(builder.Configuration["ConfluentCloud:BootstrapServerHost"], configureHost =>
            {
                configureHost.UseSasl(saslConfig =>
                {
                    saslConfig.Mechanism = SaslMechanism.Plain;
                    saslConfig.Username = builder.Configuration["ConfluentCloud:API_KEY"];
                    saslConfig.Password = builder.Configuration["ConfluentCloud:API_SECRET"];
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

*MassTransit - Consumer*

```
services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.UsingInMemory((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });

    x.AddRider(rider =>
    {
        rider.AddConsumer<[...TOPIC_CONSUMER...]>();

        rider.UsingKafka((riderContext, kafkaFactory) =>
        {
            kafkaFactory.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslSsl;
            kafkaFactory.MessageMaxBytes = 2500000; //DOES NOT WORK...
            kafkaFactory.Host(builder.Configuration["ConfluentCloud:BootstrapServerHost"], configureHost =>
            {
                configureHost.UseSasl(saslConfig =>
                {
                    saslConfig.Mechanism = SaslMechanism.Plain;
                    saslConfig.Username = builder.Configuration["ConfluentCloud:API_KEY"];
                    saslConfig.Password = builder.Configuration["ConfluentCloud:API_SECRET"];
                });
            });


            var consumerConfig = new ConsumerConfig()
            {
                GroupId = "<GROUPID>",
                AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Latest,
                EnableAutoCommit = false
            };

            kafkaFactory.TopicEndpoint<[...Event...]>(
                topicName: "<TOPIC NAME>", consumerConfig, kafkaTopicReceiveEndpointConfig =>
                {
                    kafkaTopicReceiveEndpointConfig.ConfigureConsumer<[...TOPIC_CONSUMER...]>(riderContext);
                });
        });
    });
});
```

*Confluent Cloud*

Limitations confluent has is that a message can be up to 8 MB, but still even though I confiured the topic to allow at least 2.5MB it will still not produce messages to this topic when they are larger than 1 MB...

2500000 bytes = 2.5 MB (Rounded Megabytes)
[image: Confluent Topic Config]

Image size calculation code in JavaScript (very simple):

```
const fileInBytes = file.size;
const IsSmallFile = (fileInBytes / 1024 /*=kb*/ / 1024 /*=mb */) < 2; //In my frontend I use 2 MB as limitation but allow 2.5 MB through the Kafka topic which is fine.
```

Actual image size calculated in frontend:

[image: Image Size]

Error I'm receiving:

[image: Error in backend]

Can someone please tell me what is going on, because I do not get it fully and could not find any solutions online to solve it..

Comment: Do you know which librdkafka setting does `MessageMaxBytes` set?

Comment: I'm making use of https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/tutorials/examples/clients/docs/csharp.html and this is done via the UI basically

Comment: I understand, but all those settings are passed down into librdkafka config - https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md , so if `MessageMaxBytes` in C# doesn't work, then it needs to be traced into that C library for the actual client

Comment: I'm using Confluent Cloud and they handle this for me. They provide a UI to me where I can basically configure the settings which then I think, under the hood, updates the librdkafka. However, I'm just confused why it wouldn't work... I'm not sure if this is a MassTransit or a Confluent Cloud issue. I can even be the one who just lacks of knowledge on this particular topic, I don't know...

Comment: Confluent Cloud has no control over your client code. No, it doesn't use librdkafka. Topic settings aren't the same as client settings

Comment: I'd suggest running Kafka locally, create topics with the same max message bytes setting, then run your code against that to debug where the issue is. Then you can either file an issue with MassTransit or Confluent Cloud, or Confluent dotnet library

Comment: Otherwise, Kafka is not intended for file transfers. Use a CDN or filesystem like S3. Then send a file URI as a string via Kafka, and download files by address rather than deserialize from Kafka

Comment: Thanks for the input @OneCricketeer. I'll look into your suggestions.